# Use python to connect to sqlplus in a remote host and execute sql commands

Tags: python, oracle, python-2.7, ssh, paramiko

Here is my situation :
We have sqlplus set up in a remote machine and I want to connect to that remote machine and then run sqlplus to execute sql queries. I am trying to write a python script to do that.

Here is my code:

```
import sys

import getpass

import paramiko

import time

user=raw_input('Enter User Name :')

 #host_name=raw_input('Enter Host Name:')

psswd=getpass.getpass()

ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()

ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())

ssh.connect('xxx.hostname.xxx',port=22, username=user, password=psswd)

command='export ORACLE_HOME=/opt/app/oracle/product/10.2.0.2/client export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$ORACLE_HOME/lib \
 sudo -S -H /XX/XX/XX/bin/sqlplus'



print 'running remote command'

print(command) 

stdin, stdout, stderr=ssh.exec_command(command)

stdin.write(psswd+'\n')

stdin.flush()

for out in stdout.readlines():

    print out

ssh.close()
```

I have two issues here
First is if i pass command like this

```
'export ORACLE_HOME=/opt/app/oracle/product/10.2.0.2/client export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$ORACLE_HOME/lib \
sudo -S -H /XX/XX/XX/bin/sqlplus' +' echo $ORACLE_HOME'
```

I get an empty response even if I have added echo that means that variable is not set correctly.

Secondly, I can't figure out what next to do here. How to provide `username/password` to sqlplus to allow executing sql queries and then how to supply sql statements.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue as you and eventually wrote a library to do this.  Here's a snippet of 'psuedo psuedo code' that should point you in the right direction.
Keep in mind these are methods of a class and you'll need to adapt this pseudo code to your needs. Keep in mind you'll already need a SSHConnection from paramiko here.

```
   def sqlplus_cmd(self, command):
        # Create string which exports environmental variables from OracleEnv class ()
        if 'CYGWIN' not in <return from 'uname' on the host>:
            # If NOT Cygwin, concatenate environmental variable exports
            oracle_exports = 'export PATH={0}:$PATH;' \
                             'export ORACLE_HOME={1};' \
                             'export ORACLE_SID={2}'.format(<oracle_path>, <oracle_home>, <oracle_sid>)
        else:
            # If Cygwin, need to source environmental variables for shell session from script
            # TODO: May need to get Oracle Home and Path as well for some systems.
            self.cmd('echo "export ORACLE_SID={0}" > /tmp/sid'.format(<oracle_sid>))
            oracle_exports = 'source /tmp/sid'

        # Issue concatinated one line command which exports variables, opens sqlplus, and issues a sqlplus statement
        # final_command = oracle_exports + ';' + 'echo "' + command + '" | sqlplus -S / as sysdba'
        final_command = '{0};echo "{1}" | sqlplus -S / as sysdba'.format(oracle_exports, command)
        stdout, stderr, rc = <paramiko_SSHConnection.exec_command>(final_command)
```

That should do it. Have fun parsing the output and catching the ORA-xxx and SP2-xxx errors in stdout.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you split your command into a function, and use subprocess.Popen() to execute it in a subprocess?

```
from subprocess import *

def run_sql_query(sql_command, connection_string):
    session = Popen(['sqlplus', '-S', connection_string], stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
    session.stdin.write(sql_command)
    return session.communicate()
```

Then you can pass your connection string and command as arguments to your function:

```
con_str = 'xxx.hostname.xxx',port=22, username=user, password=psswd'
cmd = ''export ORACLE_HOME=/opt/app/oracle/product/10.2.0.2/client export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$ORACLE_HOME/lib sudo -S -H /apollo/env/envImprovement/bin/sqlplus'

print(run_sql_query(con_str, cmd))
```